# Documentation for touchscreen events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, mobile

Where can I find documentation or a reference for touchscreen events in Javascript, ex.  "touchstart".

I found this useful link http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/ (**EDIT:** page no longer exists) where the events "touchstart", "touchmove" and "touchend" are mentioned for IPhone.

Are there more? What about Blackberry and Android? I did not find much on SO and Google.

**Edit**
Here is a good documentation by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: Remember touchstart and touchend fire on multi point touch too

Comment: Your 'useful link' does not work :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used this site when developing a mobile web app http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

But with research I have gotten a decent list.

- touchstart

  - Action: fires when the screen is touched (will fire for multi-point touches as well)
  - Equivalent: mousedown
- touchend

  - Action: fires when a finger is lifted from a screen (is really finiky with single point touch
  - Equivalent: mouseup
- touchmove

  - Action: fires when one or more fingers move on the screen
  - Equivalent: mousemove
- touchcancel

  - Action: when a touch event is canceled by the system
  - Equivalent: none that I'm aware

Other touch devices map the touch events to mouse events. Others ignore touch events.

To a [Google API discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/5f79c3ae7d217552) - "Apart from mobile safari, there isn't a way to access touch events on 
desktops that have a touch screen."

Comment: have you tested whether the events work the same way on other devices/browsers, not just the iPhone?

Comment: I have tested on iphone, ipad, and htc droid they worked fine

Comment: Will it work on a cheapo Samsung, running Android 2.3? *(sorry, I know this answer is ancient...)*