# Touch Events In Jquery seem devoid of useful information

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I am trying to make a web app work on tablets. I don't actually need the guesture stuff from the tablets, just the equivelent of mousedown mouseup and mousemove.

However, the touch events seem to interfere, and don't seem to provide the coordinate data I need.

What I really want is the equivalent of clientX, clientY or similar, but these touch events don't have them, on the iPad for sure. And the mouse events seem to get eaten by the touch events. There also seems to be no other fields in the event data I can leverage.

I don't want to add jq mobile or ui to bulk up the code. It seems

Suggestions?

I wrote this fiddle to capture what the different types of event. It just grabs the event and prints the contents of the event object skipping a bunch of common fields:

http://jsfiddle.net/fraserorr/DBe6A/1/embedded/result/

Code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id='abc'></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#abc { width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;}
```

JS:

```
function f(e) {
    for(var i in e) {
        if(i == "isImmediatePropagationStopped") continue;
        if(i == "isPropagationStopped") continue;
        if(i== "stopImmediatePropagation") continue;
        if(i == "stopPropagation") continue;
        if(i == "preventDefault") continue;
        if(i == "handleObj") continue;
        if(i == "data") continue;
        if(i == "delegateTarget") continue;
        if(i == "attrChange") continue;
        if(i == "attrName") continue;
        if(i == "relatedNode") continue;
        if(i == "srcElement") continue;
        if(i == "altKey") continue;
        if(i == "bubbles") continue;
        if(i == "cancelable") continue;
        if(i == "ctrlKey") continue;
        if(i == "currentTarget") continue;
        if(i == "eventPhase") continue;
        if(i == "metaKey") continue;
        if(i == "relatedTarget") continue;
        if(i == "shiftKey") continue;
        if(i == "target") continue;
        if(i == "view") continue;
        if(i == "which") continue;
        if(i == "button") continue;
        if(i == "buttons") continue;
        //if(i == "clientX") continue;
        if(i == "clientY") continue;
        if(i == "fromElement") continue;
        //if(i == "offsetX") continue;
        if(i == "offsetY") continue;
        //if(i == "pageX") continue;
        if(i == "pageY") continue;
        //if(i == "screenX") continue;
        if(i == "screenY") continue;
        if(i == "toElement") continue;
        if(i.substr(0, 6) == "jQuery") continue;
        if(i == "timeStamp") continue;
        if(i == "isDefaultPrevented") continue;
        //if(i == "type") continue;
        if(i == "originalEvent") continue;
        $("#log").prepend(i + ": " + e[i] + "<br/>");
    }    
}    
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("#abc").on("mousemove", f);
    $("#abc").on("mousedown", f);
    $("#abc").on("touchmove", f);
    $("#abc").on("touchstart", f);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719142/documentation-for-touchscreen-events-in-javascript) post :

**touchstart**

Action: fires when the screen is touched (will fire for multi-point touches as well)

Equivalent: mousedown

**touchend**

Action: fires when a finger is lifted from a screen (is really finiky with single point touch).

Equivalent: mouseup

**touchmove**

Action: fires when one or more fingers move on the screen.

Equivalent: mousemove

To get equivalent of clientX, clientY :  Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UTKzF/15/light/) fiddle only from touch device.

```
 touchMe[0].ontouchstart = function(e) {        
    log.html("Touch Start");
    var touche= e.touches[0]; 
    //instead of e.clientX, in touch event we have to acess like this    e.touches[0].clientX.
    log.append("X :" + touche.clientX + "Y :" +touche.clientY);
    log.append("</br>");
}
```

Also, [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931172/x-y-touch-coordinates-for-ios-mobile-devices) may help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Touch devices might be a bit temperamental. Android acts differently than iOS, etc.
After lots of debugging I've found that this routine works well (for the sake of simplicity I'm using only an X value):

```
var getCurrentValue = function( sourceEvent ) {
    var value = sourceEvent.pageX;

    // Android
    if ( !value && sourceEvent.touches && sourceEvent.touches.length ) {
        value = sourceEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    }

    // iOS
    if ( !value && sourceEvent.changedTouches && sourceEvent.changedTouches.length ) {
        value = sourceEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    }

    return value;
};


var $elem = $( 'section' );


$elem.on( 'mousedown touchstart', function( event ) {
    var x = getCurrentValue( event );
    console.log( 'START:', x );
});


$elem.on( 'mousemove touchmove', function( event ) {
    var x = getCurrentValue( event );
    console.log( 'MOVE:', x );
});


$elem.on( 'mouseup touchend', function( event ) {
    var x = getCurrentValue( event );
    console.log( 'END:', x );
});


$elem.on( 'touchcancel', function( event ) {
    console.log( 'AWW SNAP! Apple firing a cancel event, because they can\'t fix Safari performance issues.', event );
});
```

Pay your attention to the `touchcancel` event as it might kick in when your move handler takes more than a split second to execute.

Fiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/6fcbZ/